No linebreak in lettrine drop cap sentence
I'm writing a book in tufte-book (TeXShop 5.46, Mac OS 13.6.9) and want the first paragraph in each chapter to be full text width.  I'd also like a drop cap (implemented with lettrine).  Here's a minimal example:
\documentclass[twoside,symmetric]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{lettrine-2022-09-25} % Drop caps

\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter} 

\begin{fullwidth}
\lettrine[image=false,lines=3,findent=0pt,nindent=1pt]{\textcolor{violet}{T}}{his is the first sentence in the chapter, but it is so long that it does not wrap at the full width of the text.}  Here is a second sentence.
\end{fullwidth} 

Here is a third sentence.

\section{Introduction} 

My first section...

\end{document}

Unfortunately, for some reason the long first sentence within \fullwidth is not automatically broken at the end of the textwidth, though the remaining text is.  Of course I could manually force a line break, but even that leads to ragged justification on the right.
How do I ensure the first sentence (rendered in all caps) is properly broken at the end of the line?

it's normally only the first word in the lettrine small caps argument, you want the whole sentence even if it spans multiple lines?

it doesn't make a lot of difference but \usepackage{lettrine-2022-09-25} is not teh intended way to access the 2022 release, \usepackage{lettrine}[=v2.3] would input that file explicitly as a versioned release of lettrine This has teh benefit of telling other packages that lettrine is loaded, should they test for that.

@David Carlisle:  Yes... I'd like the entire first full sentence in all caps.

lettrine places it all in a box to prevent any line breaking, so that will require a bit of surgery on the package, just looking now...

@David Carlisle:  I really appreciate it...

I'd define a command to do the job.
\documentclass[twoside,symmetric]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{lettrine} % Drop caps
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\startchapter}[3]{%
  % #1 = lettrine, #2 = text in small caps, #3 = further text
  \begin{fullwidth}
  \lettrine[image=false,lines=3,findent=0pt,nindent=1pt]{\textcolor{violet}{#1}}{}%
  \textsc{\ignorespaces #2} \ignorespaces #3\par
  \ifnum\prevgraf<3 \ifnum\prevgraf<2 \mbox{}\par\fi \mbox{}\par\fi
  \end{fullwidth}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter} 

\startchapter{T}{
  his is the first sentence in the chapter, but it is so long that it 
  does not wrap at the full width of the text.
}{
  Here is a second sentence.
}

Here is a third sentence.

\section{Introduction} 

\lipsum[2]

\lipsum[3]

\chapter{Second chapter} 

\startchapter{T}{
  his is the first sentence in the chapter.
}{
  Here is a second sentence.
}

Here is a third sentence.

\section{Introduction} 

\lipsum[2]

\lipsum[3]

\chapter{Third chapter}

\startchapter{T}{
  his is the first sentence in the chapter, but it is so long that it 
  does not wrap at the full width of the text.
}{
  \lipsum[3][1-3]
}

Here is a third sentence.

\section{Introduction} 

\lipsum[2]

\chapter{Fourth chapter}

\startchapter{T}{
  his is the first sentence in the chapter, but it is so long that it 
  does not wrap at the full width of the text.
}{
  \lipsum[3]
}

Here is a third sentence.

\section{Introduction} 

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}


Look at the other examples for different lengths of the special text.

Perfect.  Thanks so much!


lettrine clearly only intends one or two words to be in this argument and boxes them to keep them together. One simple solution would be to take all but the end of the first word out of the argument and put the rest in a normal \textsc but here I locally redefine \usebox to unbox its argument to allow line breaks.
Incidentally I left \usepackage{lettrine-2022-09-25} but the intended syntax (assumeing you really need an old version) is \usepackage{lettrine}[=v2.3]
\documentclass[twoside,symmetric]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{lettrine-2022-09-25} % Drop caps

\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter} 

\begin{fullwidth}
  {\def\usebox#1{\leavevmode\unhbox#1}\lettrine[image=false,lines=3,findent=0pt,nindent=1pt]{\textcolor{violet}{T}}{his
    is the first sentence in the chapter, but it is so long that it
    does not wrap at the full width of the text.}}  Here is a second
  sentence.
  
\end{fullwidth} 

Here is a third sentence.

\section{Introduction} 

My first section...

\end{document}


The issue with the text not breaking is only because you are forcing an old version of lettrine. As noted in comments it does not occur with the current version.

\documentclass[twoside,symmetric]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{lettrine} % Drop caps

\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter} 

\begin{fullwidth}
  \lettrine[image=false,lines=3,findent=0pt,nindent=1pt]{\textcolor{violet}{T}}{his
    is the first sentence in the chapter, but it is so long that it
    does not wrap at the full width of the text.}  Here is a second
  sentence. 
\end{fullwidth} 

\bigskip

Here is a third sentence.

\section{Introduction} 

My first section...

\end{document}


Are you aware that the issue you mention, no longer occurs with lettrine version 2.40 and above ? Precisely, the \usebox command was replaced by \unhcopy (the purpose was to allow footnotes and microtype's action on the second mandatory argument).

@DanielFlipo I did try to hint that the OP had offered no indication why they were forcing an old copy of lettrine, I must admit I hadn't noticed that the whole issue goes with the current version. I'll add that to my answer thanks!
